# `[` and dplyr::select within mutate return different results

Tags: r, select, dplyr

Consider the following data set

```
require(dplyr)
df <- data_frame(
  "a" = c(NA, 1:2),
  "b" = c(1:2, NA),
  "c" = c(3:2, NA),
  "d" = 10:12
)
```

This works as expected

```
df_new <- df %>% 
  mutate("e" = rowSums(df[c("a", "b")], na.rm = TRUE))
```

This however returns an error

```
df_new <- df %>% 
  mutate("e" = rowSums(select(df, a:b), na.rm = TRUE))
```

> ```
> Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : NA/NaN argument
> In addition: Warning messages:
> 1: In c(NA, 1L, 2L):c(1L, 2L, NA) :
>   numerical expression has 3 elements: only the first used
> 2: In c(NA, 1L, 2L):c(1L, 2L, NA) :
>   numerical expression has 3 elements: only the first used
> ```

I dont understand this behavior since `rowSums(select(df, a:b), na.rm = TRUE)` works as expected returning a vector which mutate should simply append. Any explanations?

Comment: The second one is also working fine in the devel version of `dplyr`

Comment: Works as expected for me

Comment: a better dplyr strategy would be `rowwise %>% mutate(e = sum(a,b,na.rm = T)`

Comment: Thanks seems to have been an issue with a previous version. thanks also for the strategy hint @Nate Day